# Boot repair with bootable usb stick fails

Tags: ubuntu, boot, nvidia, bootrepair

I try to fix the problem that my PC is not booting.
(After an update to ubuntu 22.04, I removed Nvidia drivers and also did an apt auto remove assuming to get rid of some not deprecated packages. When I restarted the system, it didn't boot, i.e. it got stuck after POST)

I try to do some troubleshooting following [this post](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-not-booting-troubleshooting-guide). But I can also not boot into the live environment from a bootable usb stick on which I installed an ubuntu 22.04 image.

- In the UEFI I changed the booting order to boot from the stick at first
- I disabled secure boot and fast boot

When I boot the PC (with connected stick) I see in the POST report that the stick is recognized. Then follows a boot menu where I can choose "Try or Install Ubuntu" and some other options. After choosing "Try Ubuntu" I get just a black screen with a blinking white cursor in the top corner...

Has somebody an idea what my problem could be?

Comment: 1. For these modern Linux distros, leave Secure Boot on. 2. Since the USB flash drive *started* to boot, most there was an issue when making it. Create it again, following the directions at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview , https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview, or https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ ,